# How to exclude data points more than 2 SD from sample mean in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R as below and want to exclude datapoints that are more than 2 SDs from the sample mean. I need to do this by condition.
So, specifically, I need to group by Condition, and then exclude datapoints more than 2 SDs from the mean of medErr.
Any tips on how to do this (I use tidy verse but am a bit stuck)

Thanks!

| Nr | ID | Sex | Age | Condition | meanErr | medErr | varErr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21343 | female | 19 | Causal | 1.589679618 | 1.545205213 | 0.93076650 |
| 2 | 21343 | female | 19 | Non-Causal | 1.002208099 | 1.009241219 | 0.45208960 |
| 3 | 21363 | female | 20 | Causal | 3.138516587 | 2.630161424 | 5.74271903 |
| 4 | 21363 | female | 20 | Non-Causal | 1.512882702 | 1.245398206 | 1.24308910 |
| 5 | 21368 | female | 20 | Causal | -0.425156892 | -0.382225350 | 0.04519723 |
| 6 | 21368 | female | 20 | Non-Causal | 0.431359690 | 0.433967936 | 0.14884018 |

Comment: You don't have enough data to do this by `Condition` (or even for all data). `mean(dat$medErr) + c(-2,2)*sd(dat$medErr)` ranges from `-0.96` to `3.12`, and none of `medErr` is outside of that range ... and that's looking at all data, this is also the case for each `Condition`.

Comment: @r2evans there is a 3.138 in the data

Comment: Right, good catch @Onyambu (I started writing that per-Condition, didn't put as much attention into the whole-data check, thanks)

Comment: Sorry folks -- this is only the first few rows of the data set. I don't understand how to paste the entire frame and format it correctly. SO I did this by hand. I thought 6 rows is enough to illustrate the basic problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Condition) %>% 
  mutate(out = case_when(
    medErr > mean(medErr, na.rm=TRUE) + 2*sd(medErr, na.rm=TRUE) ~ 1, 
    medErr < mean(medErr, na.rm=TRUE) - 2*sd(medErr, na.rm=TRUE) ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  filter(out == 0)
```

Comment: A bit more direct: `dat %>% group_by(Condition) %>% filter(between(medErr, mean(medErr) - 2*sd(medErr), mean(medErr) + 2*sd(medErr)))`.

Comment: Cool, @r2evans!  I always learn new and interesting things from your interventions.

Comment: Fantastic @DaveArmstrong and @r2evans! Thank you! What would I need to do if instead of excluding the identified datapoints, I want it to exclude the entire participant? I.e. IF a participant had an outlier score in either their "Causal" or "Non-Causal" condition row of medErr (or both)?

Comment: Using DaveArmstrong's code, perhaps replace `filter(..)` with `group_by(ID) %>% filter(any(out == 0))`.

Comment: @r2evans -- thanks, but that does not quite work. It seems to filter out only those cases where out == 1 in for both values of condition...

Comment: I think I have solved it: Replace ```filter(..)```  with ```group_by(ID) %>%filter(!(any(out == 1)))```